# require('.') differs from require(__filename);

Tags: node.js

Doing metaprogramming kinda stuff and I was looking into a file requiring its own exports, like so:

```
exports.foo = 'bar';

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(require(__filename).foo);
},100);
```

it turns out the above works fine, however this doesn't seem to:

```
exports.foo = 'bar';

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(require('.').foo);
},100);
```

does anyone know why `require('.')` would differ from `require(__filename)`?

Comment: `'.'` resolves to `__dirname`, not `__filename`

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stand-alone (or leading) period, in a module path, is a shorthand for the current folder or directory rather than the current file.

```
console.log(require.resolve('.') === __dirname); // true
```

Requiring `'.'` involves the process of [folders as modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules), that retrieves the `exports` from either an `index.js` or a configured `"main"` script.

Using [`require.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options), you can see the absolute path that `require()` will read from:

```
console.log(require.resolve('.'));        // e.g. "/path/to/index.js"
console.log(require.resolve(__dirname));  // e.g. "/path/to/index.js"
console.log(require.resolve(__filename)); // e.g. "/path/to/foo.js"
```